# create .bacpac file programmatically from azure database .Net core 3.0

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core

I'm trying to create local database backups in .bacpac format from my mssql azure database. I was able to generate .bacpac files in .net framework 4.6 using [DacsServices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dac.dacservices?view=sql-dacfx-140.3881.1), however this is not supported in .net core 3.0.

What would be a good alternative to DacServices for .net core 3.0?

Edit:

I want to save the backups programmatically, i have written a scheduler to trigger the update function every day.

Comment: The easiest way of creating a backup is to deattach the database from server and then copy the mdf file in windows.  Then reattach the database.  The copy can be attach to any server including having two copies of the same daatabase.

Comment: @jdweng i presume this is a manual approach?

Comment: You can write a query.  One approach is to use the command line utility SQLCMD.EXE which you can add queries (including attach and deattach).  See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/command-prompt-utility-reference-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15.  Power Shell also has the SQLCMD methods built in.

Comment: @jdweng this doesn't look like a .net core 3.0 approach to me though? im trying to create bacpac files using c#

Comment: You can archive entire database with mdf file instead.

Comment: If you want bacpac see following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10

Comment: Isn't the problem with backing up the database by detaching it that the database is offline during the period it is being backed up?